# Dynamic Sidebar - How to add data from database to my sidebar automatically

Tags: python, django

This is my first project with Django. I am working on a scholarship system whereby the admin has the power to add new countries, which offer scholarships, to the system. Everything works well at the level of the database. I am able to add a new country and save it.
However, it is automatically supposed to be added to the sidebar of the admin dashboard (templates). But this does not happen.

**Here is my views.py code for adding and saving a new country**

```
def add_country(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
         form = CountryForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            print(form.cleaned_data)
            return redirect('dashboard.html')   #redirect to be changed

    else:
        form = CountryForm()

    return render(request, 'add-country.html', {
        "form":form
    })
```

```
class CountryListView(ListView):
    template_name = "base.html"
    models = Country
    context_object_name = "countrys"
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<li><a href="#" class="ttr-material-button">
<span class="ttr-icon"><i class="ti-email"></i></span> 
<span class="ttr-label">Countries</span>
<span class="ttr-arrow-icon"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>
</a>
<ul>

{% for country in countrys %}

<li><a href="#" class="ttr-material-button"><span class="ttr-label">{{ countrys.name }}</span></a
</li>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access `name` attribute of each country using `countrys.name` instead of `country.name`.
html file:

```
<li><a href="#" class="ttr-material-button">
<span class="ttr-icon"><i class="ti-email"></i></span> 
<span class="ttr-label">Countries</span>
<span class="ttr-arrow-icon"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>
</a>
<ul>

{% for country in countrys %}

<li><a href="#" class="ttr-material-button"><span class="ttr-label">{{ country.name }}</span></a
</li>

{% endfor %}
```

Also, in your CountryListView, change the `models = Country` to `model = Country`

Comment: Thank you. However, I made the changes but it still doesn't work.

Comment: On your views, ` return redirect('dashboard.html')` should actually be returning the viewname and not  the html template  try changing it to 
` return redirect(dashboard)  `
Also, `models = Country` to `model = Country` in your `models.py` ,(but i assume you've already tried that.